# How it became possible for integer and character be added and return a summation of integer type?

Tags: c++, char, integer, ascii

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a = 77;
    int b = a + 3;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Look carefully, `a`  is holding the character `'M'`, according to its ASCII value 77. Variable `a` is actually returning `'M'` here. How can you store `M+3=80` in an `int` type variable?

Comment: fun fact: `77` is of type `int`. So actually your confusion already starts at the first line.

Comment: `char a` is an _integer_ type with a value of 77. `int b` is an _integer_ type with a value of 77 + 3 or 80.  `cout` prints out text based on the value and type of the obejct.

Comment: The value of `a` is `77`. It's `cout` that handles `char` differently from other integer types, it assumes you meant to print the corresponding character and not the numeric value.

Answer (score 4):

The type `char` is an integral type. Full stop. There is nothing magical about a `char` that says it has to represent a character. So

```
char a = 77;
```

does exactly the same thing as

```
int a = 77;
```

except that `char` could be smaller than `int`, so might have a more limited range of values that it can represent.

Similarly,

```
int a = 'A';
```

assigns the value of `'A'` to `a`, just as

```
char a = 'A';
```

would.

And, finally,

```
char a = 77;
a = a + 1;
```

does exactly the same thing as

```
int a = 77;
a = a + 1;
```

does. They're both integer types, and they both store integer values.

The place where `char` differs is in the functions that do input and output. For example,

```
char ch = 'A';
std::cout << ch << '\n';
```

will display the character `A`, while

```
int i = 'A';
std::cout << i << '\n';
```

will display the numeric value of the character `A`, That value depends on the character encoding that the compiler uses; that's almost always ASCII theses days, but that's not required.

Comment: char x =77; std::cout<<x<<std::endl ; Why x actually return a character instead of returning 77 itself?  @Pete

Comment: @SamiulIslam — the **type** of `x` is `char`; the **value** of `x` is 77. The library code that implements `std::cout << x` does different things, depending on the type of `x`. When the type of `x` is `char` (as in your code snippet) the library displays the character that the value of `x` represents. For other integer types it converts the value into decimal digits and displays those digits.